# longtable parenthesis

Tags: longtable, parentheses

I need to add a mathematical text at the left of a `longtable`. For example

```
U_d=leftparenthesis (longtable here) rightparenthesis
```

How do we add the text "Ud =" at the left of a `longtable` and how do we add parentheses to a `longtable`?

I have the following matrix and I need to convert this matrix into a longtable matrix, because it must be on two pages. Although I was looking to import a new page into `\left(\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}`, I could not find anything.

```
\begin{eqnarray*}

        U_d=\left(\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
         0         & 0          & 1        & 2               \\
         0         & 0          & 2        & 3               \\
         \vdots    & \vdots     & \vdots   & \vdots            \\
         0         & 0          & 10       & 11                \\

\hline

         1         & 1          & 11       & \multirow{4}{*}{permut$\{{2, 11}$\}} \\ 
         1         & 1          & 12       &                        \\
         \vdots    & \vdots     & \vdots   &                         \\
         1         & 1          & 20       &                       \\

\hline 

         0         & 1          & 21       & 22                   \\
         0         & 1          & 22       & 23                     \\
         \vdots    & \vdots     & \vdots   & \vdots                   \\
         0         & 1          & 30       & 31                  \\

\hline

         1         & 0          & 31         & \multirow{4}{*}{permut$\{{22, \ldots, 31}$\}}          \\
         1         & 0          & 32         &                                                             \\
         \vdots    & \vdots     & \vdots     &                                                              \\
         1         & 0          & 40         &                                                              \\
\end{array}
\right),
\end{eqnarray*}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why do you want to use `longtable` here? Is there no option to use a mathematical array-like environment?

Comment: Please show an example of what you've tried so far.

Comment: there is nothing to the left or right of a longtable. In order to allow page breaking the table has to control  the full width of the page.

Comment: Do you really intend a `longtable` (= a more-than-one-page-long table) or a big matrix? Are there text or math expressions in your table? And if you really intend a `longtable`, do you want a parenthesis for every page or what else? Could you please edit your question adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of your table and also an image of what you want to achieve (also a photo of a manual drawing is enough)?

Comment: This matrix really is not very big why do you want it to break over a page? If it does break over a page what do you want to happen to the brackets? It will be very confusing for your readers if this splits over a page.